# Regarding calculation of Date

Tags: custom

I have created the order in  salesforce in todays date,deleivery date2 is we have to calculate the intermediate date between 30/09/2016 and 30/09/2017,how to calculate the intermediate date between this year, i want single intermediate date and also i want two intermediate dates between this year.

> for example : 1,2,3

intermediate 2 like that

then 1,2,3,4

intermediate date 2,3 like that

what is the formula for finding the intermediate date for all particular one year gap for single date and also two dates how? Please anyone Guide me for the Answer,suppose some year contains 366 days how?

Comment: you want t find it in apex or formula field?

Comment: i want to place the value in trigger @TusharSharma

Comment: for particular year one intermediate date and also i want to calculate for two intermediate dates

Comment: @ apex tushar sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `date1.addmonth(6);` or `date1.addmonths(18)`. it will give you intermediate dates. You don't need to worry about any month Sf will handle it.

Here date1 can be today or your start date.